# Acumular consulta en variable n veces durante un while

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo un TSQL que me trae el `rowcount` de ciertas tablas para varias base de datos. Y efectivamente me hace el `rowcount`, pero no logro que me arroje el resultado unificado. Ahora mismo trae esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando debería traerme todo unificado.

He pensado que lo apropiado sería acumular lo resultados y luego que la variable me arroje el total luego de pasar por todas las base de datos, pero no encuentro la manera de aplicar esta lógica al código.

Este es el código, espero haberme explicado bien y que puedan ayudarme.

```
USE master;
GO
DECLARE @HFM_DB varchar(100)
DECLARE @ROWCOUNT varchar (800)
DECLARE @BASE varchar (800)

DECLARE Cursor_DB CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name like '%HFM%'
OPEN Cursor_DB
FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_DB INTO  @HFM_DB 

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS= 0)
BEGIN
                SET @BASE=N'USE'
                --SELECT @BASE
                SELECT @ROWCOUNT= @BASE + ' ' +@HFM_DB + N' SELECT ''' +@HFM_DB + N''' as DB_name,
                               t.NAME as [table_name], 
                               i.rows 
                FROM ' + @HFM_DB+ '.sys.tables t INNER JOIN sysindexes i ON (t.object_id = i.id AND i.indid < 2) 
WHERE t.name LIKE ''%_DATA_AUDIT'' OR t.name LIKE ''%_TASK_AUDIT'' OR t.name=''HFM_ERRORLOG'''
   FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_DB INTO  @HFM_DB;
  -- SELECT @ROWCOUNT
  EXEC sp_sqlexec @ROWCOUNT
  END;

CLOSE Cursor_DB;
DEALLOCATE Cursor_DB;
```

Comment: Hola Kyana, bienvenid@ a [es.so]. Tengo una pregunta, ¿deseas que la información de las dos consultas esté presente solamente en una sola? Es decir que ¿de los 6 registros que se muestran solo obtengas uno solo con todos los resultados sumarizados?

Comment: Tienes que concatenar **en texto** las consultas de cada iteración, algo como `@ROWCOUNT = @ROWCOUNT + 'UNION '...`, ya al salir del bucle ejecutar recién `EXEC sp_sqlexec @ROWCOUNT`.

Comment: Hola Flxtr, Si, exactamente eso es lo que estaba necesitando, perdon por no saberme explicar de la mejor manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te indicaba en el comentario, tendrías que construir tu consulta y almacenar el resultado de cada consulta en un consolidado.

```
USE master;
GO
DECLARE @HFM_DB VARCHAR(100)
   ,@Consulta VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE Cursor_DB CURSOR
FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name LIKE '%HFM%';
OPEN Cursor_DB;
FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_DB
INTO @HFM_DB;

SELECT @Consulta = '
DECLARE @Consolidado AS TABLE(
    [DB_name] VARCHAR(MAX),
    table_name VARCHAR(MAX),
    rows BIGINT
);'

WHILE (
          @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      )
BEGIN

    SELECT @Consulta = @Consulta + 
         N'USE ' + @HFM_DB + N'; 
INSERT INTO @Consolidado
SELECT 
    ''' + @HFM_DB + N''',
    t.NAME, 
    i.rows 
FROM ' + @HFM_DB + '.sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sysindexes i 
    ON (t.object_id = i.id AND i.indid < 2)
WHERE 
    t.name LIKE ''%_DATA_AUDIT'' 
    OR t.name LIKE ''%_TASK_AUDIT'' 
    OR t.name=''HFM_ERRORLOG'';';

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_DB
    INTO @HFM_DB;

END;

SELECT @Consulta = @Consulta + '
SELECT DB_name, table_name, rows FROM @Consolidado;'

EXEC sp_sqlexec @Consulta;
--PRINT @Consulta;

CLOSE Cursor_DB;
DEALLOCATE Cursor_DB;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Davlio! El consolidado era lo que me estaba faltando :)

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente debes usar `SUM`, y no poner las filas de cada tabla:

```
USE master;
GO
DECLARE @HFM_DB varchar(100)
DECLARE @ROWCOUNT varchar (800)
DECLARE @BASE varchar (800)

DECLARE Cursor_DB CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name like '%HFM%'
OPEN Cursor_DB
FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_DB INTO  @HFM_DB 

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS= 0)
BEGIN
                SET @BASE=N'USE'
                --SELECT @BASE
                SELECT @ROWCOUNT= @BASE + ' ' +@HFM_DB + N' SELECT ''' +@HFM_DB + N''' as DB_name,
                               SUM(i.rows) rows
                FROM ' + @HFM_DB+ '.sys.tables t INNER JOIN sysindexes i ON (t.object_id = i.id AND i.indid < 2) 
WHERE t.name LIKE ''%_DATA_AUDIT'' OR t.name LIKE ''%_TASK_AUDIT'' OR t.name=''HFM_ERRORLOG'''
   FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_DB INTO  @HFM_DB;
  -- SELECT @ROWCOUNT
  EXEC sp_sqlexec @ROWCOUNT
  END;

CLOSE Cursor_DB;
DEALLOCATE Cursor_DB;
```

Comment: Gracias! Pero en realidad no es eso lo que necesito. El query esta bien. Lo que necesito es guardar cada iteracion en la misma variable para que al final me arroje un solo resultado de todo y no por separado.

Answer (score 0):

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqBGh.png)Trata de agrupar tu t-sql de manera que quede asi:

> SELECT t.NAME as [table_name], sum(i.rows) as Rows FROM sys.tables t 
>     INNER JOIN sysindexes i ON (t.object_id = i.id AND i.indid < 2) 
>   WHERE t.name LIKE 'TMP%' 
>   GROUP BY t.NAME 
>   WITH ROLLUP

Espero haber ayudado

Comment: Gracias! Pero en realidad no es eso lo que necesito. El query esta bien. Lo que necesito es guardar cada iteracion en la misma variable para que al final me arroje un solo resultado de todo y no por separado.

Comment: Pero al final al hacer el ROLLUP te arroja una linea con el total, pruebalo                                                                                                                        
table_name                                 Rows
---------------------------------------- -----------
TMPEncuesta                             4054
TMPEncuesta_Detalle                91151
TMPENCUESTA_RESULTADO  46
TMPENCUESTATEMPO             439
tmpObservacionPositiva             0
NULL                                          95690

Answer (score 0):

Por empezar, `sp_sqlexec` entiendo está "deprecado", lo correcto sería usar `sp_executesql`. Mas allá de eso, la única alternativa es "insertar" los registros obtenidos en cada consulta dinámica en una tabla temporal creada afuera del ciclo.

Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE #Resultados (
             db_name    VARCHAR(255),
             table_name VARCHAR(255),
             rows       INT
```

)

Luego dentro del ciclo, le agregas a tu query dinámico:

```
INSERT INTO #Resultados (db_name, table_name, rows)
```

Por último al salir del ciclo

```
SELECT db_name, table_name, rows
       FROM Resultados
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda usar GROUP BY y su clausula ROLLUP

```
USE master;
GO
DECLARE @HFM_DB varchar(100)
DECLARE @ROWCOUNT varchar (800)
DECLARE @BASE varchar (800)

DECLARE Cursor_DB CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name like '%HFM%'
OPEN Cursor_DB
FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_DB INTO  @HFM_DB 

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS= 0)
BEGIN
                SET @BASE=N'USE'
                --SELECT @BASE
                SELECT @ROWCOUNT= @BASE + ' ' +@HFM_DB + N' SELECT ''' +@HFM_DB + N''' as DB_name,
                               t.NAME as [table_name], 
                               sum(i.rows) as ROWS 
                FROM ' + @HFM_DB+ '.sys.tables t INNER JOIN sysindexes i ON (t.object_id = i.id AND i.indid < 2) 
WHERE t.name LIKE ''%_DATA_AUDIT'' OR t.name LIKE ''%_TASK_AUDIT'' OR t.name=''HFM_ERRORLOG'' **GROUP BY ''' +@HFM_DB + N''', t.NAME WITH ROLLUP'**
   FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_DB INTO  @HFM_DB;
  -- SELECT @ROWCOUNT
  EXEC sp_sqlexec @ROWCOUNT
  END;

CLOSE Cursor_DB;
DEALLOCATE Cursor_DB;
```